# Concrete5 - Using pretty URLs in SiteMap 'Visit' link

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, concrete5, pretty-urls

Using Concrete5 v5.6.3.1 I have pretty URLs enabled and they are working as expected.

Let's say I created a page named 'test' that is accessible from the pretty URL:

```
http://<root_url>/my_awesome_test
```

When I click on the page in the SiteMap UI and choose 'visit' I'm still linked to the non-pretty, cID-based URL:

```
http://<root_url>/index.php?cID=139
```

Since I have pretty URLs enabled, is there any way for the 'visit' link on the sitemap to use the pretty URL instead of the cID-based one?

I'm not saying that I want to remove the cID-based URL, that's obviously required as a fallback, but when pretty URLs are enabled it just doesn't make sense to not also use them, even on the internal SiteMap UI. I often find myself wanting to link a page I'm working on in the sitemap, and then always have to look under properties to get the pretty URL, which is really tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it looks like that the sitemap is using some javascript that is hard coded to use the cID. I'd agree that it would be nice for this to be implemented. I doubt you have much luck with getting a pull request into the 5.6 version, but you could always suggest it be implemented in 5.7 (if it isn't already?)

Here's the code where it's getting set currently in 5.6:
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/51badcdb1f00b5ba07ba11e02e4422e76da107ac/web/concrete/js/ccm_app/sitemap.js#L45

And here's where you can report an issue for the new 5.7 version if you'd like to see it implemented: 
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-5.7.0/issues

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's unfortunate, but makes sense. I'll  request it.